# Flex, rendering of descending element fails

Tags: css, flexbox

Attached a sample. I am building a grid component, where the first column of the body can be frozen, the header supports pivoting of data and without having to set fixed width/heights. (the latter is deceivably difficult to accomplish because there is no easy end fast way to calculate the visible portion of elements inside an overflow:hidden box without moving up the entire DOM chain)

So I tried to make use of flex-box for its flexible nature to scale with the viewport available. Unfortunately I have an element that is not being rendered properly.

You can see the element .bodywrap .frozen with the backgroundcolor lime, being the issue. The rendering stops mid-way 'European Union'.

The content is rendered, but the background color is not. I can mitigate this by reading (.body).offsetHeight and then apply this as a fixed height via scripting but I prefer a CSS only solution if I can.

Anything I can do to solve this one?

```js
function Throttle(ms, callback) {
    let lastCall = 0;
    return function () {
        let now = new Date().getTime(),
            diff = now - lastCall;
        if (diff >= ms) {
            lastCall = now;
            callback.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}

function Grid(){
    this.head = document.querySelector('.head');
    this.body = document.querySelector('.body');
    this.frozenBody = document.querySelector('.bodywrap>.frozen');
    
    this.body.addEventListener('scroll', Throttle(5, this.Scroll.bind(this)));
}
Grid.prototype = {
    Scroll : function(){
        let scrollLeft = event.srcElement.scrollLeft;
        let scrollTop = event.srcElement.scrollTop;

        this.head.style.transform = `translateX(-${scrollLeft}px)`;
        this.frozenBody.style.transform = `translateY(-${scrollTop}px)`;
    }
}
new Grid();
```

```css
html,margin{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
.outer{
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:100px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.grid{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    height:100%; /* remove if outer has no height */
    flex-direction:column;  
}
.headwrap{
    display:flex;
    flex:1 0 auto;  
    flex-direction:row;     
    margin-right:20px; /* scrollbar width, to be calculated runtime */
    overflow:hidden;
    background:blue;
}   
    .headwrap .frozen{
        flex:0 0 auto;
        background:lime;
        z-index:1;
        /*display:none;*/       
    }
    .head{
        flex:1 1 auto;
        z-index:0;
    }
.bodywrap{
    display:flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    flex-direction:row;         
    overflow:hidden;    
}
    .bodywrap .frozen{
        flex:0 0 auto;
        background:lime;
        margin-bottom:20px; /* scrollbar height, to be calculated runtime * / 
        z-index:1;
        /*display:none;*/
    }
    .body{
        flex:1 1 auto;
        overflow:auto;
        background:silver;
        z-index:0;
    }
td{
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="headwrap">
            <div class="frozen">
                <table border="1" style="width:150px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="head">
                <table border="1" style="width:2000px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">2020</td>
                        <td colspan="4">2021</td>
                        <td colspan="4">2022</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Q1</td>
                        <td>Q2</td>
                        <td>Q3</td>
                        <td>Q4</td>
                        <td>Q1</td>
                        <td>Q2</td>
                        <td>Q3</td>
                        <td>Q4</td>                     
                        <td>Q1</td>
                        <td>Q2</td>
                        <td>Q3</td>
                        <td>Q4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bodywrap">
            <div class="frozen">
                <table border="1" style="width:150px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>North America</td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr>
                        <td>European Union</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Africa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Asia</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Africa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>South America</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Central America</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <table border="1" style="width:2000px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>                      
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess if you move the translateY from frozen div to table inside it.  it will work

Comment: Correct, because the parent element will not move; e.g. it will hide the underlying rendering issue because the contents will stay within the painted area. 

But unfortunately this is not a structural solution and I'd like to understand why this element is not re-painted.

Also interestingly, the margin-bottom is also completely ignored when you start scrolling; painting content in the area without respecting the applied margins. 

Have a slight feeling I am hitting rendering bugs with the Chromium engine.

Comment: you did not redraw the frozen div you change only the style attribute of it and the height of it is correct because the div.outer height is 400px and the default of align-items  in flex is stretch in your case available height for frozen div is 200px